# Can I save memory by replacing list elements with None in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have millions of rows of data like these:

```
    ["1.0.0.0/24", 16777216, 16777471, "1.0.0.0", "1.0.0.255", 256, 13335, "AU", false, true, false, false],
    ["1.0.1.0/23", 16777472, 16777983, "1.0.1.0", "1.0.2.255", 512, null, "CN", false, false, false, false],
    ["1.0.3.0/24", 16777984, 16778239, "1.0.3.0", "1.0.3.255", 256, null, "CN", false, false, false, false]
```

I saved them in JSON files and also in an SQLITE3 database. I am going to pull all the data from the database at the start of a script, to make the data querying happen entirely in memory, thus save time by not using the slow filesystem calls.

And this also means it will take a lot of memory, I measured the memory usage of the data to be about 500MiB. I will put them into a `list`, I use binary search to find the index of closest starting IP address that is less than or equal to any given IP address, and then determine if the IP is inside the network located at the index. (I will pull the starts and ends out of the `list`)

If the IP is inside the network, the data will be put into a custom class to make the result strongly typed, the result will be cached so next time if the query is called with the same argument the cached result will be retrieved to save processing time, and the element located at the index will be deleted before the result is returned. (The key will be the index as well as the argument)

Because I use binary search, naturally this requires that the indices to be invariant, but I want to remove the unnecessary element from the `list` to save memory, and this will cause the indices to change.

A simple solution to this problem is to not delete the element at the index, but assign the `list` element located at the index to `None`. Another solution would be to convert the `list` to a `dict` with the indices as keys, but of course this would use more memory than using a `list`.

But I don't know if doing so would save memory, I tried to create `list`s with the same length and containing the same element at all indices, and it seemed that `list`s of the same length always have the same size, and the size of elements don't matter:

```
In [200]: ([None]*18).__sizeof__()
Out[200]: 184

In [201]: ([None]*180).__sizeof__()
Out[201]: 1480

In [202]: ([0]*180).__sizeof__()
Out[202]: 1480

In [203]: ([object]*180).__sizeof__()
Out[203]: 1480

In [204]: (['']*180).__sizeof__()
Out[204]: 1480

In [205]: (['abcs']*180).__sizeof__()
Out[205]: 1480

In [206]: (['abcdefg']*180).__sizeof__()
Out[206]: 1480

In [207]: ({i: e for i, e in enumerate(['abcdefg']*180)}).__sizeof__()
Out[207]: 9296

In [208]: 9296/1480
Out[208]: 6.281081081081081

In [209]: ([('abcdefg', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)]*180).__sizeof__()
Out[209]: 1480
```

So can replacing `list` elements with `None` save memory? If not, then what is a better way to remove items while keeping indices?

---

It seems that a `list` containing a row of the data repeatedly also has the same size at the same length:

```
In [221]: import json

In [222]: l = json.loads('["1.0.0.0/24", 16777216, 16777471, "1.0.0.0", "1.0.0.255", 256, 13335, "AU", false, true, false, false]')

In [223]: l
Out[223]:
['1.0.0.0/24',
 16777216,
 16777471,
 '1.0.0.0',
 '1.0.0.255',
 256,
 13335,
 'AU',
 False,
 True,
 False,
 False]

In [224]: ([l]*180).__sizeof__()
Out[224]: 1480
```

---

I have made some other tests, but the result doesn't make sense:

```
In [224]: ([l]*180).__sizeof__()
Out[224]: 1480

In [225]: l.__sizeof__()
Out[225]: 168

In [226]: l = [l]*180

In [227]: l.__sizeof__()
Out[227]: 1480

In [228]: l[0:12] = [None]*12

In [229]: l.__sizeof__()
Out[229]: 1480

In [230]: list(range(180)).__sizeof__()
Out[230]: 1480
```

It seems that the size of a `list` is only related to its length and not related to its contents whatsoever, but this simply can't be true.

---

No the binary search won't be broken, since I will store the starting IP of networks as integers in a separate list, and ending IP of networks as integers in yet another list, and these two lists will not change.

It's like this:

```py
STARTS = [row[1] for row in data]
ENDS = [row[2] for row in data]

store = {}
def query(ip):
    if ip in store:
        return store[ip]
    index = bisect(STARTS, ip) - 1
    if index >= 0:
        if not STARTS[index] <= ip <= ENDS[index]:
            return
        if index in store:
            result = store[index]
            store[ip] = result
            return result
        row = data[index]
        data[index] = None
        result = Network(row)
        store[index] = result
        store[ip] = result
        return result
```

I didn't actually write working code, though writing it is trivial, I just don't know if this would end up saving memory.

---

I have benchmarked the SQLite3 query and found it to take around 40 milliseconds to complete a single query:

```
In [232]: import sqlite3

In [233]: conn = sqlite3.connect('D:/network_guard/IPFire_locations.db')

In [234]: cur = conn.cursor()

In [235]: cur.execute('select * from IPv4 where start_integer = 3113839616;')
Out[235]: <sqlite3.Cursor at 0x20b5d9c66c0>

In [236]: cur.fetchone()
Out[236]:
('185.153.108.0/22',
 3113839616,
 3113840639,
 '185.153.108.0',
 '185.153.111.255',
 1024,
 3242,
 'IT',
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0)

In [237]: %timeit cur.execute('select * from IPv4 where start_integer = 3113839616;')
38.8 ms ± 805 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [238]: cur.execute('select * from IPv4 where start_integer = 3113839616;')
Out[238]: <sqlite3.Cursor at 0x20b5d9c66c0>

In [239]: %timeit cur.fetchone()
58.8 ns ± 0.672 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000,000 loops each)
```

---

Using `bisect` takes under 1 microsecond to complete the same query, and there are 567778 rows for IPv4 addresses and 446631 rows for IPv6 addresses, for a total of 1014409 rows. Just fetching all the rows and creating the `lists` take about 500MiB memory.

```
In [246]: cur.execute('select * from IPv4;')
Out[246]: <sqlite3.Cursor at 0x20b5d9c66c0>

In [247]: data = cur.fetchall()

In [248]: STARTS = [row[1] for row in data]

In [249]: bisect(STARTS, 3113839616)
Out[249]: 366233

In [250]: %timeit bisect(STARTS, 3113839616)
341 ns ± 6.43 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)

In [251]: len(data)
Out[251]: 567778

In [252]: cur.execute('select * from IPv6;')
Out[252]: <sqlite3.Cursor at 0x20b5d9c66c0>

In [253]: data6 = cur.fetchall()

In [254]: len(data6)
Out[254]: 446631

In [255]: 567778 + 446631
Out[255]: 1014409
```

I determined the memory usage by using Task Manager, just by checking the memory usage of the process right before fetching the rows and right after fetching the rows, to calculate the difference.

If I create all instances of custom classes upfront, I don't think I have enough RAM for all the objects even though I have 16GiB (I open multiple tabs in browsers and the browser take multiple GibiBytes of RAM, so I don't have much available RAM).

And I won't make any more edits to this post.

Comment: If I understand correctly the output of your tests, Python is realizing that the elements in the list are the same, thus implicitly saving memory at least in an initial version. I would think that if you change some of the elements in the lists you create with repeated elements, the size will be increased.

Comment: If my understanding is correct, `__sizeof__()` is returning the size of the list itself, but not the size of the whole data structure it points to, so it doesn't matter if it contains pointers to None or pointers to big complex objects in memory. When you replace a list element with None, that should enable the Python garbage collector to release the memory eventually, so there should be some savings over time.

Comment: But there's no guarantee you'll really see those savings: you're freeing little bits of RAM here and there in your process space, unless you free a lot, it's not that likely to actually reduce the process's RAM usage.

Comment: Putting aside the memory issues, this is going to break your binary search.

Comment: It seems you are doing the things that the SQL engine would do for you. Are you sure your implementation will be faster than leaving the search to the SQL database engine? I would think that over decades of tuning, SQL database engines are particularly good at managing what goes into memory, how to best index a dataset for fast access, ...etc, provided you define the right index(es). Have you benchmarked the two solutions?

Comment: *"If I create all instances of custom classes upfront"* - That actually could reduce the memory usage. Depends on you class.

Comment: Note that this is a pretty common problem for routers (if I understand your problem correctly) and there are quite some optimized algorithms for it. A trie comes to mind, although python doesn't make it easy to provide very efficient implementations of one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your big list object (containing the 1014409 rows) takes ~8 MiB memory. The remaining ~492 MiB are for your row list objects. That's ~485 bytes per row. So yes, you could save hundreds of bytes for each row you replace with `None`. (How much depends on how many of its element objects stay alive due to being referenced elsewhere.)